# How do I make text appear in chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you make text appear in the chat, without the player pressing a button or stepping on a pressure plate, etc.

Confusing, I know, so let me explain.

Let's say in an adventure map, the player(s) will be fighting a boss, while they're fighting the boss, the boss will say something like "Haha! You'll never take me down!" But the player(s) don't press a button or anything.

Am I being stupid? I've been looking for the answer to this for a while now and I really want to know, as I'm attempting to make an adventure map.

Comment: Question is very valid, title could be better IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You could activate it based on a player's location, so when a player reaches a certain point it progresses the story. In an always on repeating command block put:

`execute if entity @a[x=,y=,z=,dx=,dy=,dz=] as someBoss run say You'll never defeat me!!`

You'll need to fill in the x y and z coords and the x y and z distances, or just use a `distance=` tag (which might actually be easier), and customize the message. You can change the name someBoss to whatever the name of your boss is. Alternatively, just put the command block under the floor where you want it to activate and use only the distance tag, so you don't need coords for every message you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Set it up on a timer. Once it reaches a certain amount of ticks, say a random thing of dialogue and then reset.

Example:

`scoreboard objectives add bossTimer dummy`

`scoreboard players add @e[type=boss] bossTimer 1`

`execute @e[score_bossTimer_min=40,score_bossTimer=40] ~ ~ ~ /say Hi`

`scoreboard players set @e[score_bossTimer_min=40,score_bossTimer=40] bossTimer 0`

Comment: Would you mind linking me a video tutorial or explaining it in more detail? I've attempted that multiple times and it hasn't worked properly, so I believe I'm doing it wrong, because of course I am. :P

Comment: @Jazzzy Which Minecraft version are you using? this answer only works for 1.12.2 and below.